# ASP.NET Calendar with multiple months showns together

Tags: asp.net, calendar

In my asp.net application there is a requirement where there is a textbox and right next to the textbox there is a calendar image. When I click the calendar image a calendar should come up and I should be able to select a date in a month.

Normally I could use AjaxcontrolToolkit calendar control, but the problem here is that here I have to show two consecutive months together side by side. And there is an arrow at the left side of one month and an arrow at the right side of the other month so that I can navigate to other months.

How can I do this? Are there any controls like this or should I create it by myself? If I have to create it myself, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,
http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Calendar/Designs/Windows%20(Multi-Month)/Demo.aspx

Comment: Also take a look at this http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Calendar/Features/Multi-Month%20Calendar/Demo.aspx